# Shorthand for variable assignment based on OR expression

Tags: javascript, angular, logical-operators

Is there a shorthand for the assigning of a variable to an OR expression? For example, I have a button on my UI that is disabled depending on the state of some variables.

`this.disableButton = data && data.items.length < 2 && pending;`

I also have a checkbox that determines whether or not said button will be disabled or enabled.

So, the button finally is disabled/enabled based on an expression that looks like this:

`this.disableButton = this.disableButton || !checked`

And on my template, I have something like:

`<component [class.disabled]="disableButton"></component>`

I was just curious if there were a way to shorten the syntax of the above expression. Something like:

`this.disableButton ||= !checked`

Thanks

Comment: You could use `<component [class.disabled]="disableButton || !checked"></component>`, and avoid combining `disableButton` and `checked`. As for the operator, see [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189479/why-there-are-no-compound-assignment-operators-for-logical-operators-such-as).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be more straightforward to assign to `disableButton` all at once rather than assign an intermediate value to the result first and then reassign later - that's confusing. Because `checked` alone can determine the result, it'll be clearest if you examine it first:

```
this.disableButton = !checked || (data && data.items.length < 2 && pending);
```